# Aggregate, Date, Values

Tags: r, aggregate

I am new to R and am trying to aggregate the results and find min of dates. For example if I have

```
ID       Date         Value
 0     2013-06-02       1
 0     2013-04-02       3
 0     2013-02-02       5
 1     2013-08-02       6
 1     2013-04-02       7
 1     2013-12-02       9
```

The result I am looking for is like:

```
ID       Date         Value
 0     2013-02-02       5
 1     2013-04-02       7
```

Any times would be appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies.

I had the following query inmind:

Result<- aggregate(DF_1[,c("Date"),], by=list(DF_1, DF_2) , min)

but it simply gave me the min date, but not the value corresponding to it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
data.table(df)[, .SD[which.min(Date), ], by=ID]
```

You could also use `dplyr` (thanks Ananda):

```
library(dplyr)
df %.% group_by(ID) %.% filter(Date == min(Date))
```

Both produce something like:

```
   ID       Date Value
1:  0 2013-02-02     5
2:  1 2013-04-02     7
```

Comment: Note that `which.min(.)` (`data.table` solution) will give only the first index in case of multiple values, where as the `dplyr` solution with `==` will give you *all* the minimum dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clumsy looking base R approach:

```
mydf[as.logical(with(mydf, ave(as.numeric(Date), ID, 
                               FUN = function(x) x == min(x)))), ]
#   ID       Date Value
# 3  0 2013-02-02     5
# 5  1 2013-04-02     7
```

It adapts my "dplyr" recommendation to @BrodieG with `ave`.

Answer (score 1):

Though less pretty than data.table and dplyr:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) x[which.min(x$Date), ]))

##   ID       Date Value
## 0  0 2013-02-02     5
## 1  1 2013-04-02     7
```